# Diferença italic e emphasis em HTML?

Tags: html, html5, formatação

Qual a diferença das tags `<i>` e emphasis `<em>` em HTML?

**Quando utilizar cada uma delas?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tag `<em>` tem significa **enfatizado**. Você deve usá-la quando você quer estressar um determinado pensamento ou ideia. Os navegadores normalmente tornam o texto enfatizado em *itálico*; Um leitor pode recitar o texto um pouco mais lentamente ou mais alto do que as palavras que o cercam.

*Exemplo:*

```html
A rota é perfeitamente segura desde que você permaneça na fuga. Acima de tudo, <em> não andam no intervalo de disparo </em>.
```

Às vezes, você precisa enfatizar o texto, não para fazê-lo se destacar, mas para esclarecer o significado. Por exemplo, se eu colocar um sinal dizendo **Escolha seus próprios morangos**, eu estou convidando você a comprar morangos de mim, no entendimento de que você possa pegá-los. Mas se eu disser **Escolha os seus `<em>`próprios `</em>` morangos**, eu estou dizendo para você deixar os meus morangos quietos.

A tag `<i>` também faz com que o texto a ser processado em itálico, mas neste caso é para fins de estilo em vez de adicionar ênfase. Você usa `i` para indicar uma voz ou modo diferente, ou para separar uma frase ou palavra do fluxo normal do texto.

A etiqueta é usada frequentemente para os títulos dos filmes, dos livros e das obras ou da arte, para nomes de navios, para frases estranhas curtas, e em certos usos especializados, tais como teoremas matemáticos e nomenclatura biológica. Mas note que todos esses usos são uma questão de estilo; 
Exemplo:

```html
Ele passou o tempo recitando<i> o tiroteio de Dan McGrew</i>.

Apesar de perder cada jogo, mantivemos nosso <i> esprito de corpo</i>.
```

[FONTE](http://hexcentral.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/bold-italic-em-and-strong-understanding.html)

Answer (score 3):

Apesar do resultado visual ser o mesmo, pois os dois deixam o conteúdo em itálico, o significado semântico é diferente. A tag `<em>` é usada para dar ênfase no conteúdo e a tag `<i>` é usada para o estilo do texto em geral.

```html
<p>
  Essa <em>palavra</em> merece ser enfatizada 
</p>
  
  
<p>
  <i>Quero deixar todo meu texto em itálico<i/>
</p>
```